# Vue.js vee-validate how to avoid error after submitting available input

Tags: vue.js, vee-validate

I am validating input in my AddItemComponent.vue... 
It's working fine, displaying the error message when entering empty string , not showing error when user enter any value...
However after adding the item, the input field is cleared but the error message get displayed ( I am not using v-validate.initial )

I tried to insert: this.$validator.clean() after adding the item .. wo any success

**UPDATE**

I understand what happen , but I don't see how to solve it ..
after adding item , the method 'addItem() create a new empty item to clear the input field ... this raises the validation error again...

**AddItemComponent**

```
    <template>
      <div>
        <div class="input-group">
          <input type="text" name="item" data-vv-delay="500" v-validate="'required'" :class="{'input': true, 'is-danger': errors.has('required') }"  @keyup.enter="addItem" v-model="newItem" placeholder="add shopping list item" class="form-control">
          <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button @click="addItem" class="btn btn-default" type="button">Add!</button>
          </span>
        </div>
        <p v-show="errors.has('item')">{{ errors.first('item') }}</p>
      </div>
    </template>

    <style scoped>
    p { color: red; }
    span, input, button { vertical-align: top; }
    </style>

    <script>
      export default {
        props: ['id'],
        data () {
          return {
            newItem: ''
          }
        },
        methods: {
          addItem () {
            var text

            text = this.newItem.trim()
            if (text.length > 0) {
              this.$emit('add', this.newItem)
              this.newItem = ''
            }
            this.$store.dispatch('updateList', this.id)
          }
        }
      }
    </script>
```

Comment: debugging w vue-dev-tools, added an UPDATE in the question

Comment: Can you make a working demo ?

Comment: yes , you can access my current tuts project at :   https://github.com/erwin16/ShoppingLists   , see src/components/...

Answer (score 3):

A s per vee-validate collaborator answer ...

> This is because of the timing issues, With Vue when you set a reactive property or data item that is bound on the UI it is not updated immediately, there is a small propagation delay. after which the component updates which triggers the validator to validate, so the error shows again.

You can fix that by using the reset method wrapped inside a nextTick handler

so I fixed it as following :

```
    <script>
      export default {
        props: ['id'],
        data () {
          return {
            newItem: ''
          }
        },
        methods: {
          addItem () {
            var text

            text = this.newItem.trim()
            if (text.length > 0) {
              this.$emit('add', this.newItem)
              this.item = ''
              this.$nextTick(() => {
                this.$validator.reset()
              })
            }
            this.$store.dispatch('updateList', this.id)
          }
        }
      }
    </script>
```